# How to set the keyboard layout using the terminal?

Tags: keyboard-layout

My keyboard layout is currently US. I need it to be a UK layout. I've tried the following which works but applies the change to the current session only. I need the change to be persistent.

```
setxkbmap gb
```

How can I permanently change my keyboard layout from US to UK?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in /etc/default/keyboard:

```
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
```

If it is a graphical desktop, like Gnome, make sure that keyboard settings are not reset by the desktop config utility by disabling it.

Alternatively, you could add the `setxkbmap gb` command to autostart applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this change didn't seem to work. Will I need to restart? I'm using LXDE (trusty 14.04).

Comment: Just tried a system restart, which didn't help.